# CSS positioning (relative, absolute inside relative) + overlapping issue?

Tags: html, css, css-position, bootstrap-select

I have a structure like this 
https://jsfiddle.net/znpruua1/

However, I am having trouble at http://wereviewapp.com/App/Post

[image: Absolute Container , inside relative container]

Login at : http://wereviewapp.com/Login
Credentials:

```
email : info@wereviewapp.com 
pass : xtyxty1
```

in the second combobox named category cannot display it's dropdown properly.

**I have had already solved the issue** :

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu {
  max-height: 192px !important;
  max-height: 19.2rem !important;
}
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-menu .inner {
  max-height: 140px !important;
  max-height: 14rem !important;
}
```

However, is there any other good approach?

*My concern is to learn what is causing the problem.* Why I need to add that max-height? It should work just fine as it was in the jsfiddle.

**All the relative contents are in same level so there shouldn't be any problem. Any absolute element inside the relative container should grow and show up on top of the underlying div container.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should set a data-container, because the default one seems to be the body, and bootstrap-select injects height values by javascript. You can find more info here:

https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#container

Your main container is #wrap, so you can try adding the attribute data-container="#wrap" to your select html tag.

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-container="#wrap">
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: is there any other way to fix it from css? Without using #wrap. Since it need to put it everywhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know another only-css way, because bootstrap-select injects inline styles calculating the container height by javascript. That is why you have to override them by using !important in your css rules.